# energy consumption for communication between physical process and node module in castalia?

Tags: omnet++

When the node sends a request to physical process and when the physical process replies to a node, how much energy is consumed?
and if a physical process receives messages from a large number of nodes at a time, let's say a thousand nodes will it be able to process them or there will be some delay in processing a large number of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Castalia does not handle power consumption for sensor readings, so zero power is consumed. If you [look at the code for SensorManager.cc](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/blob/master/Castalia/src/node/sensorManager/SensorManager.cc) you can see that a lot of the infrastructure is already coded, and there is even a hint in the comments as to what you would need to do to complete this functionality:

```
// update the remaining energy of the node
// powerDrawn(pwrConsumptionPerDevice[sensorIndex]);
// Left as is the module will draw this power always, that's why it's commented out.
// We need to schedule a timer to draw 0 power after some time. How much time?
```

How quickly the simulation will handle requests from thousands of nodes will depend on the complexity and efficiency of the physical process and sensor manager. You will have to just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

James already answered about the main part of the question, but I see a confusion between real time and simulation time, that's why I am adding this answer.

> "if a physical process receives messages from a large number of nodes
>   at a time, let's say a thousand nodes will it be able to process them
>   or there will be some delay in processing a large number of requests?"

Of course the physical process will process all the messages, that's what it is designed to do. Depending on the computer you are using to run the simulation and and how complex your simulation is, this may take a lot of **real** time. But this does not mean that any **simulation** time has passed. So if 1 million nodes are asking the physical process for 1 million samples at the same simulation time, they will get back 1 million responses at the same simulation time! Even if it takes hours to run this code. Any simulation time that passes is carefully coded in the system. For example, with sensing, we have a parameter called `hysteresis` to model the delay some sensing devices experience (default is 0).

Make sure you read on the basics of event-driven simulation so you clarify the basic distinction between real time and simulation time.

Comment: yes i understand. I ran the bridgeTest simulation for 1000 nodes, the simulation time is 100 seconds and the real time it took was approximately 5 minutes on core i3.